# Nested routes that do not imply resource association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it considered bad practice (or un-RESTful) to create nested routes for resources that otherwise have no association? For example I have:

```
resources :foos do
  resources :bars
end
```

But I have no business logic elsewhere in my database or application that associates `:foos` with `:bars`.

The reason I want to do this: Many of my routes are created as resources nested under my `:groups` resource. I do that so that I can always grab a `group_id` param and always show a layout that matches the group the user is currently "in". I'm comfortable with this when the resource `belongs_to` the group:

> /groups/1/comments/1

But when some other comment does not `belong_to` the group (group1) and I want to look at it through layout that is "branded" as group1, my impulse is to route it like this:

> /groups/1/comments/2

Is this ok to do,  maybe I'm overthinking this?

Comment: Would it be possible to leverage `current_user` or some session parameter to achieve the layout-by-group functionality you want?

Comment: Hi Lanny, yeah, that makes sense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain an app with similar requirements.  I do something roughly along the lines of:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  belongs_to :active_group, class_name 'Group'

  def active_group
    return super unless super.nil?

    group = groups.first
    update_columns(active_group_id: group.id)
    group
  end
end
```

The `User` class validates that they are assigned to one or more groups and the `active_group` method is overriden to provide a default if it is a first login.  With this approach you will need to provide an action to set the active group so the user can switch groups (presumably this is a requirement).

This assumes that you have some kind of authentication in place to know the current user.  If restricting access to groups is not a concern, you can forego the habtm relationship and substitute `groups.first` with `Group.first`.

If you don't have/want/need authentication, you could just drop a `active_group_id` in the session cookie.  But I would definitely consider it bad practice to nest unrelated resources.